# How can I use a string to be the end symbol in python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, while-loop

How can I use a string to be the end symbol while I was prompting the user to input a specific integer '1' or specific string 'end' as the end symbol, just like the samples below? I now only can use '1' as the end symbol. I am a beginner, so please explain as simple as possible. Many thanks!

```
list = []
num = 0
stop = False

num = int(input('Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end):'))
if num == 1:
    print('No input!')
else:
    list.append(num)
    print(list)
    while stop == False:
        num = int(input('Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end):'))
        list.append(num)
        print(list)
        if num == 1:
            stop = True
            print('The smallest integer is', min(list))
```

sample1 output:

Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end): -56

Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end): -42

Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end): -112

Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end): -1

Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end): -89

Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end): -676

Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end): -312

Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end): 1

The smallest integer is -676

Sample2 output:

Enter a negative integer (1 or 'end' to end): -123

Enter a negative integer (1 or 'end' to end): -1

Enter a negative integer (1 or 'end' to end): -23

Enter a negative integer (1 or 'end' to end): -1144

Enter a negative integer (1 or 'end' to end): -222

Enter a negative integer (1 or 'end' to end): -23

Enter a negative integer (1 or 'end' to end): -33

Enter a negative integer (1 or 'end' to end): -33

Enter a negative integer (1 or 'end' to end): end

The smallest integer is -1144

Sample3 output:

Enter negative integers (1 to end): 1

No input!

Comment: You are need to stop not 1 but and “end” string?

Comment: Both. if the user input '1' or 'end', then the program output the minimum value that they have input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one, where 'end' is 1 as stop:

```
list = []
num = 0
stop = False

num = input('Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end):')

if num=='end':
    num=1
else: num=int(num)

if num == 1:
    print('No input!')
else:
    list.append(num)
    print(list)
    while stop == False:
        num = input('Enter a negative integer (1 or ‘end’ to end):')
        if num=='end':
            num=1
        else: num=int(num)
        list.append(num)
        print(list)
        if num == 1:
            stop = True
            print('The smallest integer is', min(list))
```

Comment: its not correct to use 'list' because its reserver word, means _<class 'list'>_, more correctly use `list1`, or `List`, but not `list `

Comment: at your code 1st need to compare `num==string_object` and then use `num=int(num)`

Comment: **Chuen Wong**, is this result what your want to get?